# How can I align an <a> tag in the center of a <div> that already has text-align applied to it?

Tags: html, css

Heres my problem: I want to center an <a> tag inside of a <div> that already has text-align applied to it. I've found a way to solve my problem by wrapping the <a> tag with 'span' tags. Is there a better way to do this, i.e. without the extra <span> tag?

Here is a fiddle that describes what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/8VhQg/3/

As you can see, I've solved the problem at the bottom, but what is it about the <a> tag that won't let it work by default? Even changing the display didn't seem to work:

```
a {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}

a {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

I would prefer not to remove the text-align from the <div>, I'm mostly curious as to why the <a> tag prefers the parent CSS instead of its own ID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will come in helpful: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+specificity&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: Is this what you're looking for...? The `id`'s were wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/8VhQg/4/

Comment: Yep, that was it. Can't believe I didn't see it when I wrote it. Still having a similar problem on my website though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to give class `center` and `left` to `<a>`.

IDs must be same. Use class instead.

Change

```
<h2>Align Links</h2>
<a href="" id="right">Right Align Link</a><br/>
<a href="" id="right">Center Align Link</a><br/>
<a href="" id="right">Left Align Link</a><br/>
```

to

```
<h2>Align Links</h2>
<a href="" class="right">Right Align Link</a><br/>
<a href="" class="center">Center Align Link</a><br/>
<a href="" class="left">Left Align Link</a><br/>
```

[Updated fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8VhQg/7/)

Comment: Don't know buddy I got one too.

Comment: ...wow. I have no idea how I missed that. Thanks for the help anyways.  I was having the same problem on my website and I'm sure I had the correct classes and IDs there, but I have since fixed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The Fiddle you've posted isn't valid because of your reuse of `ID`s, you should use `classes` instead.

However, that aside, the easiest way to make your anchor centre-align is to set it to `display: block` (which will mean it automatically takes up any horizontal space available to it), and then `text-align: center`.

Thus, you get this:

```css
div{
    text-align: left;
}

div a{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Don't know why you're getting downvoted - that would solve it AND you point out it's bad to duplicate ID's.

Comment: Thanks @patricksweeney, there's some very odd voting going on in this page!

Answer (score 2):

create 3 classes. They have to be displayed as block to add alignment.

```
.left{ text-align: left; display: block; }
.center{ text-align: center; display: block; }
.right{ text-align: right; display: block; }
```

Then apply that directly to the A tag

```
<a href="#" class="left">this is left</a>
<a href="#" class="center">this is center</a>
<a href="#" class="right">this is right</a>
```

I think this is easiest